# Are acceptance tests in Codeception supposed to run in testing environment? (Laravel4 + Codeception)

Tags: laravel-4, acceptance-testing, codeception

I am trying to run some acceptance tests in my Laravel application. While functional tests trigger testing environment, acceptance tests do not. Is it a bug or a feature of acceptance tests? The main problem why this is bothering me is the fact, that it is not using(+populating+cleanup) testing database, it only connects to dev database (which is used, when no other ENV is specified e.g. testing, production) and this often fails those tests when I run them multiple times.

This is my configuration:

**codeception.yml**

```
paths:
    tests: app/tests
    log: app/tests/_log
    data: app/tests/_data
    helpers: app/tests/_helpers
settings:
    bootstrap: _bootstrap.php
    suite_class: \PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite
    colors: true
    memory_limit: 1024M
    log: true
modules:
    config:
        Db:
            dsn: 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testdb'
            user: 'root'
            password: 'root'
            dump: 'app/tests/_data/dump.sql'
            populate: true
            cleanup: true
```

**acceptance.suite.yml**

```
class_name: WebGuy
modules:
    enabled:
        - PhpBrowser
        - WebHelper
        - Db
    config:
        PhpBrowser:
            url: 'http://localhost/'
```

**functional.suite.yml**

```
class_name: TestGuy
modules:
    enabled: [Filesystem, TestHelper, Laravel4, Db]
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I am having this same issue. My Codeception acceptance tests do NOT run under the 'testing' environment. I have tried to include Laravel4 in the acceptance.suite.yml - and that does not change anything.

Comment: From what I can tell - Codeception runs 'two' cycles of each test. One of them is run as the 'test' environment, but the second is NOT run in the 'test' environment. I can confirm this - because if you force BOTH tests to run in 'test' environment, then your routes dont work correctly (as they are normally disabled for tests).

Comment: @Fabrizio - what extra information do you need for this? I've already provided an answer?

Comment: @TheShiftExchange I can't make it work, I understand why Codeception and Laravel behave like that, but still the 2 answers below doesn't explain very well how to create a `codeception` environment for run the acceptance tests. Thanks a Lots!

Comment: I can't tell for codeception, but I hit the same wall. I solved passing a x-unit-testing header which triggers the testing environment (only if the request comes from localhost).

Answer (score 7):

"Acceptance" tests are not run in the testing environment. [The reason is when Laravel is in the testing environment, it disables filters by default](http://laravel.com/docs/testing#calling-routes-from-tests). So therefore the testing environment is only for unit and functional tests.

Acceptance tests should be run in another environment (like dev or a specific one to Codeception).

Because Codeception 2.x now uses Guzzle to get a page response, it is possible to detect when you are on your host machine and Codeception is doing a specific request. That way you can have a "testing" environment and also a "codeception" environment specifically for your acceptance tests.

If you are using Homestead, I do this in my `start.php` file to detect if Codeception is running, and specifically put it into a 'codeception' environment, otherwise I let it run my environment detection normally

```
if ((gethostname() === 'homestead') && (isset($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])) && ($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] === '127.0.0.1'))
{
    $env = $app->detectEnvironment(['codeception' => ['homestead']]);
}
else
{
    $env = $app->detectEnvironment(['dev' => ['homestead']]);
}
```

Then in my 'codeception' environment, I setup a SQLite file database, and run acceptance tests against that (which is faster than mySQL testing).

Comment: I am having the same issue, but I am using Behat and MAMP.
Do you know how can I set the environments correctly? 

I already have a *_acceptance database and a config/acceptance folder pointing to the correct database. 

In my featureContext.php file, I am setting the environment to 'acceptance'.


When the tests run Behat is using my local DB. :(

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This doesnt seem to work, is there are further explanation around this?

Answer (score 5):

First, you must understand that Codeception acceptance tests **do not** run inside the Laravel  testing environment. Rather, it uses **Guzzle to make external HTTP requests**. Assuming your acceptance tests run against localhost, you are running in your standard development environment. It is just like using your browser.

That said, here is how I use Codeception Acceptance tests to run against a Laravel testing environment. I run Vagrant with a LAMP stack on Ubuntu.

1. Edit your `/etc/hosts` file. Add `test.localhost` to the 127.0.0.1 line. Do not remove the other hosts there. If you use WAMP/MAMP/or other, it might be a similar setup.

   **/etc/hosts**

   `127.0.0.1 localhost test.localhost`
2. Setup your environment handling with Laravel. Below is code in the `bootstrap/start.php` file in your larval root dir. *pay attention to the 'testing' line.*

   **bootstrap/start.php**

   ```
   $env = $app->detectEnvironment(array(
       'local' => array('your-machine-name'),
       'testing' => array('test.localhost')
   ));
   ```
3. Make sure your codeception acceptance test is configured to hit the right domain/url. The code below is from my own acceptance tests for an API. Notice the url: sections have test.localhost. That is the url that Codeception will hit for the tests.

   **app/tests/acceptance.suite.yml**

   ```
   class_name: ApiGuy
   modules:
       enabled: [PhpBrowser, REST, ApiHelper, Db, FileSystem]
       config:
           PhpBrowser:
               url: http://test.localhost/
           REST:
               url: http://test.localhost/api/v1/
   ```

**Putting it all together**

1. We edited the `/etc/hosts` file so that Codeception can find `test.localhost`. Editing your web server config to handle test.localhost is outside the scope of this answer.
2. We edited Laravel's `bootstrap/start.php` so that it knows that any requests coming into test.localhost should run in the testing environment.
3. We edited Codeception's `acceptance.suite.yml` file to tell it to run all tests against http://test.localhost

Now, assuming the above is done correctly, you should be able to run codeception run acceptance and see the output of your tests.